# Setting Bootstrap Option from MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Converting legacy Clipper system to HTML/PHP/MySql using Bootstrap. My first attempt at these "modern" technologies :)

Generally everything ok, but am having problems with understanding how to set/get Option from an input

I have set up a form with a load of input boxes and radio buttons, which are all correctly populated from a selected MySQL row. I can repopulate the table from any alterations to these inputs.

However there is one drop-down box which is on the form, but I can't see how to pre-set it from the data, nor how to write the data back to the table.

The form data is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="classday" value ="<?php echo $acc_fetch['DayOfWeek']?>">
 <option value="0">Choose Day</option>
 <option value="1">Monday</option>
 <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
 <option value="4">Thursday</option>
 <option value="5">Friday</option>
 <option value="6">Saturday</option>
 <option value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

The value stored in the data table is numeric (1 for Monday etc.)

If the data returned by the PHP call was 3 I would have expected Wednesday to be shown, but it doesn't.

Can someone point me in the direction of doing this, and if subsequently a different day is chosen how to write that value back to the table (I'm using mysqli)

Many thanks

Comment: A select list's current value is not denoted by a `value` attribute on the `select` tag, it's denoted by a `selected` attribute on the `option` tag. I.e., you want `<option value="3" selected>Wednesday</option>`.

Comment: you can update your each option to `<option value="0" <?php echo $acc_fetch['DayOfWeek']  == 0?"selected":"" ?> >Choose Day</option>` That will make value selected

Comment: Why does "Choose Day" have a value? That seems like a mistake.

Comment: Choose Day is the default item showing in the select box if one wasn't previously selected.

Comment: Thanks Alex that works a treat - I hadn't come across the implied if before, so that's 2 things I have learned today.